# Construction of Set with required measure

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a Probability measure $P$ defined on $S = [0,1]$ satisfying $P({\{x}\}) = 0$ for any $x$ in $S$.

How can I construct a subset $A$ of $S$ such that $P(A)$ is exactly $\frac{1}{2}$?

Instead of $\frac{1}{2}$, can this construction be generalized to any $0 < k < 1$?

Comment: I have posted a detailed answer to your question. Please, let me know if you have any question regarding my answer. If my answer provides relevant / helpful information regarding your question, please, upvote it. If my answer actualy answers your question, accept it too, please. To upvote, click the triangle **pointing upward above the number** (of votes) in front of the question. To accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 8):

If $P$ has no atoms, then the image of $P$ will be $[0,1]$.
See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_(measure_theory)#Non-atomic_measures) and [also here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3919475/atoms-in-a-measure-space-and-sierpinski-theorem-for-non-atomic-measures/3919736#3919736)

The condition $P(\{x\})=0$ for any $x$ in $S$ is **not** enough to ensure that $P$ has no atoms.

For a counter-example, consider the probability space $([0,1],\mathcal{M}, P)$ where
$$\mathcal{M} =\{E\subseteq [0,1]: E \text{ or } E^c \text{ is countable} \}$$
and $P(E)=0$ if $E$ is countable and  $P(E)=1$ if $E^c$ is countable.

It is easy to check that $\mathcal{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $P$ is a probability measure. In this case, the image of $P$ is just $\{0, 1\}$.

**Remark 1**: If you assume that

1. $P(\{x\})=0$ for any $x$ in $S$  **and**
2. For every $x \in [0,1]$, $[0,x) \in \mathcal{M}$

Then
$\mathcal{M}$ contains the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $[0,1]$ and $P$ has no atoms. So the image of $P$ is $[0,1]$.

**Remark 2**: As remarked by GEdgar, in the special case presented in **Remark 1**, a nice way to see that the image of $P$ is $[0,1]$ is to note that the function $x \to P([0,x))$  is continuous , it has value $0$ at $0$ and value $1$ at $1$.

Answer (score 6):

The function $\phi(t) = \mathbb P\big([0,t)\big)$ is continuous.  Therefore it achieves all values between $\phi(0) = 0$ and $\phi(1) = 1$.

As Ramiro remarked, we have to assume $[0,t)$ is $\mathbb P$-measurable for all $t$ to do this.

---

added: $\phi(t)$ is continuous.
Use countable additivity: since $\phi(t)$ is nondecresing, $$\lim_{h \to 0+}\phi(t+h)= \lim_{h \to 0+}P\big([0,t+h)\big) = \lim_{n \to \infty}P\left([0,t+\textstyle\frac{1}{n})\right) \\
= P\left(\bigcap_{n}[0,t+\textstyle\frac{1}{n})\right) = P\big([0,t]\big)=P\big([0,t)\big)+P\big(\{t\}\big) = \phi(t)$$ and similarly for $\lim_{h \to 0+}\phi(t-h) = \phi(t)$.

Comment: Proving continuity of  \phi would require lim h->0  P([t, t+h)) to be 0. Is this trivial? I am guessing one would do this by showing that this limit is equal to P({t}) which is zero by the condition given in the original question. Might be a stupid question, but can you help me prove this formally?